# CardView white pixels in the borders

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-cardview, animator

#### Context

Hi, I'm having some issues related to the v7 CardView widget. Basically I have a fragment called FlipCardFragment, which has two child fragments within, FlipCardFrontFragment and FlipCardBackFragment. Each of the children fragments has a CardView. FlipCardFrontFragment displays the user name, the user's avatar picture, and if you tap on the card it does a flipping animation and goes to the FlipCardBackFragment, which displays the detail info of the user. You can flip back and forth between this two cards.

#### Issue

The problem here is that when I first show the FlipCardFragment, it has a couple of white pixels in the border corner.

[image]

Left picture shows the border corners with 0dp, right picture shows the border corner with 2dp.

I want to have corner borders, but if I do those white pixels show up. It's only the first time though. When I tap on the card and it does the flipping animation, the white pixels disappear.

#### What I tried so far:

- I tried any possible combination of this attributes on the CardView xml:

  app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
  app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
  android:forceHasOverlappingRendering="true"
  android:animationCache="true"
  android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
- The FlipCardFragment xml which contains the two child fragments for the front and the back of the user card, is arrange like this:

  - RelativeLayout

    - View
    - FrameLayout

      - FlipCardBackFragment
      - FlipCardFrontFragment

That view that you see there, is a View that I use to show a black overlay in the background (which is also animated with an AlphaAnimation, so it has like a fading out/in animation). The FrameLayout which I used to contain the fragments, has a padding of 16dp. I tried changing it to margin. But that didn't work either.

Comment: Did you tried app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false" ?

Comment: Yep, "true" and "false", both of them. All the attributes that I tested are listed in the question.